# Setup method to invoke function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I have a method in my class which receives a function (`Func`) as a parameter:

```
T Execute<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    ...
    return func();
}
```

I wish to mock this class, and have Moq calling the function I send to `Execute` as a parameter.

How I call `Execute`:

```
string result = await executor.Execute(async () => await GetResponse(query));
```

So I would like Moq to call GetResponse and return its value. How can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure that the question has all the info, because it is really simple:

```
    public interface I
    {
      T Execute<T>(Func<T> func);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
      var mock = new Mock<I>();
      mock.Setup(x => x.Execute<string>(It.IsAny<Func<string>>())).Returns((Func<string> x) => x());

      Func<string> myFunc = () => "test";

      Assert.AreEqual("test", mock.Object.Execute(myFunc));
    }
```

Comment: Note that I send an async Func to the method. I'm​ having trouble setting it up correctly.

Comment: Ok, I managed to set it up correctly using Task.FromResult. Thanks.

Comment: Yup, `Task.FromResult()` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cannot mock it if the code itself is baked into your code. To mock `GetResponse` makes sense only if it is some external component. Otherwise, it belongs to your class, which shouldn't mocked but should tested in the unit test.

To mock it, refactor your code similarly to this one.

```
public class Executor
{
    // IResponseProvider has the GetResponse method.
    // This interface can be mocked in test and can be injected in real environment.
    public IResponseProvider ResponseProvider { get; set; }

    public async Task<T> Execute<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        var response = await ResponseProvider.GetResponse(query);
        // do something with response...
        return func();
    }
}
```

Now you can *test* the `Executor` class along with its `Execute` method and you can *mock* the external `IResponseProvider` members to do something in a test environment:

```
[TestFixture] // MSTest: [TestClass]
public class ExecutorTest
{
    private Executor executor;
    private Mock<IResponseProvider> responseProviderMock;

    [SetUp] // MSTest: [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        // this is not a mock but the class to be tested
        executor = new Executor();

        // the external components can be mocked, though:
        responseProviderMock = new Mock<IResponseProvider>();

        // setup the mock:
        executor.ResponseProvider = responseProviderMock.Object;
        Func<string> mockResponse = () => "dummy mocked response";
        responseProviderMock.Setup(m => m.GetResponse(It.IsAny<MyQueryType>))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(mockResponse));
    }

    [Test] // MSTest: [TestMethod]
    public async Task ExecuteSuccessTest()
    {
         // Arrange
         Func<int> input = () => 42;

         // Act
         var result = executor.Execute(input);

         // Assert
         Assert.AreEqual(42, result);
         responseProviderMock.Verify(rp => rp.GetResponse(It.IsAny<MyQueryType>(), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to point out - the question was tagged `mstest` not `nunit` :)

Comment: I just want to mock Executor to call GetResponse.

Comment: @user6251216: If the executor is about to be mocked, it can be done similarly if it implements an interface